# Module installation failed/broken?

Tags: python, python-3.6

So I'm making a program to download a pdf, sounds simple so I installed the `pyPdf` module using `pip`, that worked ok, the files are where they should be(I think). When I type the line of code '`import pyPdf`' or try to import specific parts of it python returns the error '`no module named Pdf`'.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module several times, as well as many different versions of python and none have worked, I also tried doing it on a completely different computer but the exact same issue persisted

Here is a screenshot of the full error message:

[image: full error message]

First of all it has completely ignored the '`py`' before Pdf. It would be nice if someone could tell me what im doing wrong and how to fix things, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the module name is `PyPDF2`, not `pyPDF2`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: For future reference - you can `pip list` your installed modules, which will show you the correct capitalization.

Comment: Additionally, please just include the text of the error message in your actual post next time, instead of linking an image.

Comment: `Use 2.7 and linux cus windows is shit`  that's what happens for trying to be funny. Your filename contains a dot in `2.7` which is not an extension separator. Use proper file naming. Also  you probably have `pyPDF2` installed for 2.7 but you are using 3.6. Use 2.7! Is what your filename is telling you to do! (Or install it for 3.6)